# Assign leads per slot time

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, leads

can validation do this ? Max 10 leads on Slot time per branch.. For example only 10 leads must be in 10:00am(Slot Time) per Iron Man(Machine)..

Or apex/triggers will the job[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need a trigger to do this. Validation rules can only check against the current record (and related records), not arbitrary records in the database.

Comment: Thank you @fox :D